# My Shiny App generates error for load() function when deployed in Amazon-AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shiny, shiny-server

I have encountered with a strange deployment error when I tried to deploy my shiny app in AWS.

Below are my `ui.R` and `server.R` files :

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

    # Define UI for miles per gallon application
    fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            column(12,
              tableOutput('table')
            )
          )
        )
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

load('/home/ubuntu/Dat.Rdata')

shinyServer(function(input, output) {   
    output$table = renderTable(head(data.frame(1:20, 1:20), 20))
})
```

My 'Dat.Rdata' file is placed in my Home directory as in above server code.

However, above implementation generates an error when I try to view my App in Chrome:

```
18.221.184.94:3838 says
The application unexpectedly exited
Diagnostic information has been dumped to the JavaScript error console.
```

Few observations :

1. If I comment-out the line 'load('/home/ubuntu/Dat.Rdata')' my App working perfectly
2. The line 'load('/home/ubuntu/Dat.Rdata')' is working perfectly in standalone R application hosted in AWS as below:

   ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-148:~$ R

   R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
   Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

   R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
   You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
   Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

   Natural language support but running in an English locale

   R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
   Type 'contributors()' for more information and
   'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

   Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
   Type 'q()' to quit R.

   During startup - Warning message:
   Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"

   > load('/home/ubuntu/Dat.Rdata')

can somebody help me to understand why load() is failing when it is within my Shiny App.

Any pointer to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you checked whether the user that runs the app (usually called `shiny`) has reading permissions in `/home/ubuntu/`? An output from the javaScript console might be helpful.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thanks for your reply. However can you help on how can I know if shiny have that permission? do I need to run any code in console? Kindly let me know. thanks,

Comment: Just put the `.RData` file in the same directory as the app and change the path to a relative one: `load("Dat.Rdata")`. If you still get the same error, file-permissions are not the problem.